# PushviewController not working when called from a subview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk, pushviewcontroller

I'm building an iPhone app, with the following structure:
I have the **MainViewController** which consists of 2 views (like split screen).
The *first* view of them, has a button. On tap, a UItableView (**ResultTableViewController**) appears in the *second* (of the above) view:

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
  if ([(UIButton *)sender tag] == 0) {
      ResultsTableViewController *childViewController = [[ResultsTableViewController alloc] init];
      childViewController.tableView.delegate = self.results;        
      [self.results.view addSubview:childViewController.tableView];
    }
}
```

So I have a UItableView as a sub-view of a UIView.

The problem is that pushViewController() in didSelectRowAtIndexPath() of ResultTableViewController does not work (self.navigationController is nil).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DetailsViewController *detailView = [[DetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailView animated:YES];
}
```

I have tried many of the solutions I found, but nothing works.

In my MainWindow.xib, I have only MainViewController added, is that the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it.
I had to declare my MainViewController as UINavigationControllerDelegate and create a secondary NavigationController in it. I push the viewController in my new navigationController and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the view of the child controller to your controller's view, not pushing the child controller onto your navigation stack. Due to that, your child controller's navigation controller will be `nil`, since it wasn't put into the navigation controller.

Is this what you're going for?

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
  if ([(UIButton *)sender tag] == 0) {
      ResultsTableViewController *childViewController = [[ResultsTableViewController alloc] init];
      childViewController.tableView.delegate = self.results;        
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:childViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems correct but now childView does not showed at all. I guess something has to do with my .xib. In my MainViewController.xib I have a ResultsTableViewController which I have connected it with the corresponding IBOulet (results) and view.

Comment: @Andy Riordan - can you show how and where the UINavigationController is created?  Is it in the XIB or explicit code?

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailView animated:YES];
```

above line of code will push the detailview on navigationcontroller stack. Check whethere your tableviewcontroller is on that stack ?